# Why does Gson().toJson() of object with Enumeration throw StackOverflowError?

Tags: scala, gson, enumeration

```
import Tenum.Tenum
import com.google.gson.Gson

object Temp extends App {

  val gson = new Gson()
  gson.toJson(new Status("foo", Tenum.X))

  System.exit(1)
}

case class Status(id: String, tenum: Tenum)

object Tenum extends Enumeration {

  type Tenum = Value

  val X = Value
}
```

I thought it would just print:

```
{id:"foo", tenum:"X"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because Scala `Enumeration` has a field on it that is self referential, and Gson is trying to serialize it, getting stuck in an endless loop.

I'd try serializing `Tenum.X.toString` (or providing a json field on your enum) or looking around for a Scala Gson wrapper.